# Import node and edge CSV using gephi toolkit in java

Tags: toolkit, gephi

I need to develop a graph using gephi toolkit in Java. I have my node and edge data in CSV format. All the toolkit tutorials have syntax to import a gml or gexf format. Since I have 2 CSV files can anyone tell me the syntax of importing this csv's in Java using gephi toolkit jar?

Answer (score 2):

It's better for you to try to import csv file by gephi-tool-kit and gephi at the same time to see if there is any problem, now I will show you the way I found to import csv file by gephi-toolkit step by step.

---

Here I use [NetBeans IDE 8.2](https://netbeans.org/downloads/) with the [gephi-toolkit-0.9.2-all.jar](https://gephi.org/toolkit/) and refer to several demos from [github](https://github.com/gephi/gephi-toolkit-demos).

After create a new Java project and a new Java class like here my test class named *Transfer95*, of course you also need to add the gephi-toolkit jar file to your library. According to the tutorial and javadoc of gephi-toolkit, there is much changes to use the new toolkit, it seems that the import methods can be used   to import several different types of file like gexf and csv file.

The first several lines of code are the same common code to init project and get controller or container.

```
//Init a project - and therefore a workspace
ProjectController pc = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(ProjectController.class);
pc.newProject();
Workspace workspace = pc.getCurrentWorkspace();

//Get controllers and models
ImportController importController = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(ImportController.class);

//Get models and controllers for this new workspace - will be useful later
GraphModel graphModel = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(GraphController.class).getGraphModel();

//Import file
Container container;
try {
    File file_node = new File(getClass().getResource("/resourceason2/club_1_1995.csv").toURI());
    container = importController.importFile(file_node);
    container.getLoader().setEdgeDefault(EdgeDirectionDefault.DIRECTED);   //Force DIRECTED
    container.getLoader().setAllowAutoNode(true);  //create missing nodes
    container.getLoader().setEdgesMergeStrategy(EdgeMergeStrategy.SUM);
    container.getLoader().setAutoScale(true);

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
```

here I just try to import the node csv file with the same importController method of gexf in demos of **ImportExport** or **HeadlessSimple**, and it worked, but here we also need to import edge csv file to the network, and I finally found the answer from demo of **GenerateGraph** which can append new container to the current workspace, so the code of import csv file after is

```
    //Init a project - and therefore a workspace
    ProjectController pc = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(ProjectController.class);
    pc.newProject();
    Workspace workspace = pc.getCurrentWorkspace();

    //Get controllers and models
    ImportController importController = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(ImportController.class);

    //Get models and controllers for this new workspace - will be useful later
    GraphModel graphModel = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(GraphController.class).getGraphModel();

    //Import file
    Container container,container2;
    try {
        File file_node = new File(getClass().getResource("/resourceason2/club_1_1995.csv").toURI());
        container = importController.importFile(file_node);
        container.getLoader().setEdgeDefault(EdgeDirectionDefault.DIRECTED);   //Force DIRECTED
        container.getLoader().setAllowAutoNode(true);  //create missing nodes
        container.getLoader().setEdgesMergeStrategy(EdgeMergeStrategy.SUM);
        container.getLoader().setAutoScale(true);

        File file_edge = new File(getClass().getResource("/resourceason2/transfer_1_1995.csv").toURI());
        container2 = importController.importFile(file_edge);
        container2.getLoader().setEdgeDefault(EdgeDirectionDefault.DIRECTED);   //Force DIRECTED
        container2.getLoader().setAllowAutoNode(true);  //create missing nodes
        container2.getLoader().setEdgesMergeStrategy(EdgeMergeStrategy.SUM);
        container2.getLoader().setAutoScale(true);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
```

here we need to append the new container to the same workspace like

```
    //Append imported data to GraphAPI
    importController.process(container, new DefaultProcessor(), workspace);
    importController.process(container2, new AppendProcessor(), workspace); //Use AppendProcessor to append to current workspace
```

and finally check if your network is correct

```
    //See if graph is well imported
    DirectedGraph graph = graphModel.getDirectedGraph();
    System.out.println("Nodes: " + graph.getNodeCount());
    System.out.println("Edges: " + graph.getEdgeCount());
```

and that's why I advise you to test the csv file import by gephi and gephi-toolkit at the same time. And that's my dummy code,hopefully it will help you and there may be better answer.

**References**

- [Javadoc](https://gephi.org/gephi-toolkit/0.9.2/apidocs/)
- [gephi toolkit demo](https://github.com/gephi/gephi-toolkit-demos)
- [gephi forum](http://forum-gephi.org/viewtopic.php?t=6275&p=14575)